# Open an alert box if form validated

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a confirmation box if the form validated. This is my code:

*I use webshim/pollyfill for validation*

```
<script src="js-webshim/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script> 
<script>
   $.webshims.polyfill('forms');    
</script>
```

-

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="inputSuccess3">Paket:</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <select class="form-control" id="Paket" name="paket">
    </select>
</div>

<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="inputSuccess3">Miktar:</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="adet" name="adet" min="20" max="250" value="20" required>
</div>

<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="inputSuccess3">Link:</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="link" required>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
Ücret: <span id="output">40</span> Kredi
</div>
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="alert('Hello\nHow are you?')">Gönder</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    confirm("Press a button!");
    }
</script>
</div>
</form>
```

In this version, it open box, even if the form is empty. Could you help me?

Comment: add an Event listener on your submit and validate your form and show popup.

Comment: Could you show me how to make or any example? Thanks @RamaKrishna

Comment: Is it mandatory to use webshim/polyfiller ?. You can do with simple JavaScript

Comment: @Can see my working snippet below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script>
function myFunction(){
var message = document.getElementById('input').value
if(message){
  alert("me")
}
}
</script>
<form id="form">
 <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="inputSuccess3">Paket:</label>
 <div class="col-sm-9">
  <select class="form-control" id="Paket" name="paket">
  </select>
 </div>

 <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="inputSuccess3">Miktar:</label>
 <div class="col-sm-9">
  <input class="form-control" type="number" id="adet" name="adet" min="20" max="250" value="20" required>
 </div>

 <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="inputSuccess3">Link:</label>
 <div class="col-sm-9">
  <input id="input" class="form-control" type="text" name="link" required>
 </div>

 <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
  Ücret: <span id="output">40</span> Kredi
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">Gönder</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: hello thank you for your answer. In snippet, it works but when i add inside my code not work. It not open alert box.

Comment: I modified the snippet. Use a `script` tag inside your html and let me know if `alert` is fired